# Getting error Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error. Can't figure out what i need to do here

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to render a pie chart with a code that I found. But not able to view the pie chart. It keeps showing that I've failed to inject module. But I'm not sure what I'm going wrong. Checked several examples online. Nothing seem to help. Please help me out here.

***My index.html:***

```
<html ng-app="angularChartApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('pieChart', ['chart.js']);
    </script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body class="container-fluid ">
<div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title text-center">AngularJS Charts</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body container-fluid">
        <section>
            <div class="row well">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <section ng-controller="angularPieChartController" class="">
                        <div class="row lead">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">Pie Chart</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data" 
                                        chart-labels="labels" chart-options="optionsPie" 
                                        chart-colors="colorsPie" chart-options="optionsPie" 
                                        chart-click="clickme" chart-hover="hoverme" 
                                        chart-dataset-override="PieDataSetOverride">
                                </canvas>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-charts/0.2.7/angular-charts.min.js"</script>
<script src="Controllers/chartController.js"></script>
</html>
```

**chartController.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('angularChartApp', ['chart.js']); 

app.controller('angularPieChartController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ["Internet bill", "School fee", "House budget"];
    $scope.data = [100,300,700];
    //Make sure to use color codes, instead of color name.
    $scope.colorsPie = ['#90EE90', '#FF6600', '#8080FF']; 
    //PieDataSetOverride is used to draw lines to display the labels

    $scope.PieDataSetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }]; //y-axis-1 is the ID defined in scales under options.

    $scope.optionsPie = {
        legend: { display: true },
        responsive: true,  // set to false to remove responsiveness. Default responsive value is true.
        scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                  id: 'y-axis-1',
                  type: 'linear',
                  display: true,
                  position: 'left'
              }]
        }
    }

    $scope.clickme = function($event){
        alert("You've clicked upon "+$event[0]._view.label);
    }

    $scope.hoverme = function ($event) {
        alert("You hovered over " + $event[0]._view.label);
    }       
});
```

Comment: This question should be tagged with Angularjs not Angular

Comment: @GangadharGandi Just change the tags via edit, quick and simple.

Comment: I believe chart.js is external library and it need not to be included as dependency in module. You can include chart.js as the way you have included angular.js . Let me know if it helps